# Are there methods to get the modulo of a variable voltage, with reference to another (constant) voltage?

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, electromagnetism, component-selection

If, for example, one has an input voltage of 5 Volts, and one wants to obtain this voltage modulo 3, as:

$$V_\text{out} = 5\mod 3\text,$$
 then how does one perform this operation using simple circuitry?

This is perhaps an unusual question, but the aim is to try and replicate the basic programming math operations (+,-,*,/,%) using the simplest circuitry possible, and with voltages.

So far, I found this old question from 2013 on the topic, , [Is there a device to get modulo of voltage value?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/77554/72727) but over here (from what I understood), there's only the possibility of modulo 2<sup>n</sup>, n being the number of cascaded stages. If, one wants modulo 3 or 5, then how does one change/replace the circuit mentioned in the attached question's answer to do this?

There is also a circuit mentioned in this paper: https://www.academia.edu/2309394/An_8-bit_Voltage_Mode_Analog_to_Digital_Converter_Based_on_Integer_Division but even this states that the reference number for division (modulo) should be a proper power of 2?

Comment: Modulo only makes sense for integer operations. Voltages are not really integers.

Comment: If the reference voltage is fixed, and the input is bounded, there are only a small number of possible outputs. You could probably use  window comparators to select the right value. But that is really only solving a special case. Not the general case you seem to be trying for.

Comment: Use an ADC and DAC and discard the MSBs as appropriate.

Comment: There are more games to play in the frequency domain with harmonic mixing but that's not really your question

Comment: "found this old question from 2013 on the topic"  --- no link.  Please correct.

Comment: @ScottSeidman  corrected, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, you can't solve *numer*ical problems with strictly *analog* circuitry. The moment you build something that does that, it inherently, by the very definition of the word, becomes *digital*.

So, your simplest circuit that can do that is actually an ADC of sorts. In fact, sigma-delta ADCs are pretty close to that, functionally, and you'll have a fun time reading up on how they work :)